# how to add a data attribute to a formtastic form input radio collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, radio-button, formtastic, custom-data-attribute

In a formtastic form for new products, I am displaying a collection of options for radio buttons which appear as images. I need to pass a data attribute to be used client side.

A product has many images, hence product.product_images is an array of active records. I've tried variations on the code below without success.

```
<%= f.input :selected_image_url, as: :radio,
  collection: (Hash[product.product_images.map { |image| [image_tag(image.thumb), image.image_url], html: {data: {image_huge: image.huge}} }]) %>
```

the error message is unexpected ',', expecting '}'

The code below gives the error message invalid number of elements (3 for 1..2)

```
<%= f.input :selected_image_url, as: :radio,
  collection: (Hash[product.product_images.map { |image| [image_tag(image.thumb), image.image_url, {"data-image-huge" => image.huge}] }]) %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked

```
<%= f.input :selected_image_url, as: :radio, 
  collection: product.product_images.map { |image| [image_tag(image.thumb), image.image_url, {'data-image-huge' => image.huge}] } %>
```

Comment: Fantastic!  This solution also works for checkboxes, for example this: `f.input :program_indications, as: :check_boxes, collection: ProgramIndication.order(:identifier).map { |pi| [pi.name.titleize, pi.id, {'data-program-id' => pi.id}] }`